# Looping Through All Cells in a Column and checking if each cell contains a string within string

Tags: vba, excel

I run an excel report weekly and need to replace all of the values in a certain column depending on which strings are existent within the different values.

I have already learned a lot about how to loop through the column from stack overflow , as well as about the instr function but my macro still is not working. Also, many of the solutions that I have found require a actual string to search, but since this changes every time, I need to search through a range. Hoping that someone can help me figure out why...thank you in advance!

```
Sub FlagReplace()
Dim flagcell As String

rowcount = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("H:H"))
For i = 2 To rowcount
flagcell = Cells(i, 8).Value

   If InStrB(1, flagcell, "flag_green", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
       Cells(i, 8).Value = "last month"
   ElseIf InStrB(1, flagcell, "red", vbBinaryCompare) <> 0 Then
       Cells(i, 8).Value = "not last month"
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify: Are you looking for code that will find and replace all occurrences of a given string in a particular column with your own preferred value?

Comment: *my macro is still not working* is a meaningless problem description, because you've not explained what *not working* means. In what **specific way** is it **not working**? If you want help here, your first responsibility is to explain the problem you're asking us to help you solve clearly. *not working* is not useful without details. If you're not sure why, call your doctor's office and say *My body isn't working. What do I do to fix it?* and see if you get a treatment plan based on that information alone.

Comment: `Range("H2:H" & rowcount).Replace "*red*","not last month")` no loop needed.

Comment: @Dave: I am looking for the macro to replace the entire contents of the cell, if a specified string exists within that cell. To clarify, I do not what the entire string within the cell will but, but I do know that if the string within the cell contains the word "green", then I want to change the contents of that entire cell to "last month". Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Kenwhite: I'm sorry for the confusion. I mean that, when I run the macro, there are literally no changes to the sheet that I'm running it on. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need Option Compare Text to tell the InStr function to compare partial strings. On top of your module before your subs you can insert it. It will allow you to compare partial strings.

I actually wrote a very similar bit of code a few weeks ago. I copied your code into it, I used InStr instead of InStrB. Let me know if this works.

```
Option Compare Text

Sub FlagReplace()
Dim flagcell As String

rowcount = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("H:H"))

For i = 2 To rowcount

flagcell = Cells(i, 8).Value

   If InStr(1, flagcell, "flag_green") <> 0 Then

       Cells(i, 8).Value = "last month"

   ElseIf InStr(1, flagcell, "red") <> 0 Then

   Cells(i, 8).Value = "not last month"
   End If
Next
End Sub
```